# nodeJS phantom ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

## Problem

I installed phantom and using node v0.10.26

I am getting a Promise error within phantom. I did not see any dependencies that needed to be installed.

Below is the sample code from phantom that I am using

/myProject/node_modules/phantom/lib/index.js:15
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
             ^
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at Object.module.exports.create (/Users/jbyrne/git/tin-validator/node_modules/phantom/lib/index.js:15:14)
    at Object. (/Users/jbyrne/git/tin-validator/phantom.js:6:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

I upgraded node to v0.11.13 and now get 
$ node phantom.js
Exception: ReferenceError: Map is not defined

I installed phantom and using node v0.10.26

I am getting a Promise error within phantom. I did not see any dependencies that needed to be installed.

Below is the sample code from phantom that I am using

/myProject/node_modules/phantom/lib/index.js:15
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
             ^
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at Object.module.exports.create (/Users/jbyrne/git/tin-validator/node_modules/phantom/lib/index.js:15:14)
    at Object. (/Users/jbyrne/git/tin-validator/phantom.js:6:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

I upgraded node to v0.11.13 and now get 
$ node phantom.js
Exception: ReferenceError: Map is not defined

## Code

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var sitepage = null;
var phInstance = null;

phantom.create()
    .then(function(instance) {
        phInstance = instance;
        return instance.createPage();
    })
    .then(function(page) {
        sitepage = page;
        return page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    })
    .then(function(status) {
        console.log(status);
        return sitepage.property('content');
    })
    .then(function(content) {
        console.log(content);
        sitepage.close();
        phInstance.exit();
    })["catch"](function(e) {
      console.error('Exception: %s', e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of PhantomJS depends on some global objects that don't exist in Node 0.10. You can either upgrade Node to the latest stable version, or downgrade your PhantomJS to 1.x.

If you're switching between Node versions, you can do so easily with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Answer (score 0):

upgrade node to 0.12
the error mentioned is due to the line new Map() in phantom.
the Map constructor was added in node 0.12